# Create an Umbraco macro to insert custom HTML into a page

Tags: xslt, umbraco

I'm trying to create an Umbraco macro to insert some HTML into pages. The 'code behind' the macro is an xslt file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet [ <!ENTITY nbsp "&#x00A0;"> ]>
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
  xmlns:msxml="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
  xmlns:umbraco.library="urn:umbraco.library" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltCommon="urn:Exslt.ExsltCommon" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltDatesAndTimes="urn:Exslt.ExsltDatesAndTimes" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltMath="urn:Exslt.ExsltMath" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltRegularExpressions="urn:Exslt.ExsltRegularExpressions" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltStrings="urn:Exslt.ExsltStrings" xmlns:Exslt.ExsltSets="urn:Exslt.ExsltSets" xmlns:CWS.Twitter="urn:CWS.Twitter" 
  exclude-result-prefixes="msxml umbraco.library Exslt.ExsltCommon Exslt.ExsltDatesAndTimes Exslt.ExsltMath Exslt.ExsltRegularExpressions Exslt.ExsltStrings Exslt.ExsltSets CWS.Twitter ">


<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="customHtml" select="/macro/customHtml" />

<xsl:template match="/">

<!-- start writing XSLT -->
<xsl:if test="$customHtml!= ''">  

  <div>
<![CDATA[
   <xsl:value-of select="$customHtml" />
]]>
  </div>

  </xsl:if>  
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I use the macro, and feed some HTML to the xslt file through the customHtml variable, a server error is thrown:

> Length cannot be less than zero. Parameter name: length

However, when using plain text with the macro (with no HTML tags), it's fine and it displays on the page. I'm using Umbraco version 4.7.

Would anyone be able to help with this?

Comment: Looks like an error about an `xsl:param` element. But there's none in the stylesheet and no other stylesheets are included. Are there any other stylesheets that come into play? Look for: `<xsl:param name="length"` and `$length`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm not sure where the length param would be coming from . I don't think the xslt file references any other stylesheet, as it's very basic and most of the code was auto generated by Umbraco.

Comment: Does this happen with all HTML documents? Can you show a sample of one that results in this error?

Comment: Even if i just add something as simple as  `<p>TEST<\p>` the error occurs.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Umbraco - but have a look here: http://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/xslt/21559-Inserting-html-into-TinyMCE-with-a-macro-not-working

Comment: Does customHtml holds any values?

Comment: It holds the HTML code passed from the macro, to display on the page.